# Make a single insert statement

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL table named `stock_sales` which has 3 columns. I want to insert data with a single statement. Two statements do not work as expected:

```
"INSERT INTO  stock_sales (size) SELECT size FROM stock_avail WHERE id='5957';
"INSERT INTO  stock_sales (transactionid, date) VALUES ('$bill','$date')";
```

How can I do it in one statement and insert the data into a single row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```sql
INSERT INTO  stock_sales (size, transactionid, date) 
    SELECT size, '$bill', '$date' 
    FROM stock_avail 
    WHERE id='5957'
```

or

```sql
INSERT INTO  stock_sales (transactionid, date, size) 
    VALUES ('$bill', '$date', (SELECT size FROM stock_avail WHERE id='5957'))
```

Comment: Question was unclear to me. I thought of multi query . But, this one is good. `:)`

Comment: I want to redirect to add_sales.php page automatically after successfully insert data. Here is my statement: 

$sql= "INSERT INTO  stock_sales (transactionid, date, size) 
    VALUES ('$bill', '$date', (SELECT size, FROM stock_avail WHERE id='5957'))";

if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
   echo " <a href='add_sales.php'>Back to Sales</a>";

Comment: `if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){ 
 header("location:add_sales.php");
}` @user3716007

Answer (score 2):

```
$sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO  stock_sales (size) SELECT size FROM stock_avail WHERE id='5957';";
$sqlQuery. = "INSERT INTO  stock_sales (transactionid, date) VALUES ('$bill','$date')";

mysqli_multi_query($con,$sqlQuery);
```

> The **mysqli_multi_query()** function performs one or more queries against
>   the database. The queries are separated with a semicolon.

For more info, please click [Mysqli_Multi_Query - W3 Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_multi_query.asp)

Comment: Your code would insert two new rows. Is that what you want? Or do you want to insert it into only one new row?

Comment: no i want the code would insert single row @PaulSpiegel

Comment: there are no error but only insert the date of 2nd statement, then i substitute the query, same thing happen it only insert the data of 2nd query, @NanaPartykar